# How do you know that some fields in structs are arrays?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, code-signing, authenticode

I'm looking at this piece of C code from Microsoft `wincrypt.h` header file

```
//+-------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Attributes
//
//  Where the Value's PATTR_BLOBs are in their encoded representation.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// certenrolls_begin -- CRYPT_ATTRIBUTE
typedef struct _CRYPT_ATTRIBUTE {
    LPSTR               pszObjId;
    DWORD               cValue;
    PCRYPT_ATTR_BLOB    rgValue;
} CRYPT_ATTRIBUTE, *PCRYPT_ATTRIBUTE;

typedef struct _CRYPT_ATTRIBUTES {
    DWORD                cAttr;
    PCRYPT_ATTRIBUTE     rgAttr;
} CRYPT_ATTRIBUTES, *PCRYPT_ATTRIBUTES;
// certenrolls_end
```

and I'm running this example [How To Get Information from Authenticode Signed Executables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/323809/how-to-get-information-from-authenticode-signed-executables). I can see in the code that both `rgValue` and `rgAttr` are accessed as arrays, e.g.

```
pSignerInfo->AuthAttrs.rgAttr[n].rgValue[0].pbData,
pSignerInfo->AuthAttrs.rgAttr[n].rgValue[0].cbData,
```

If I haven't seen the example, I'd never get this. Is it something Windows specific or my total ignorance about struct and type declarations in C?

Comment: That's why you shouldn't use typedef unless it increases code readability.

Comment: @David Heffernan You can't know that it is not an array, it' just some fragment of the code, in the next lines that you don't see there might be `rgValue[1].cbData`.

Comment: @малинчекуров I quote my own comment, "it looks like". But actually we can know. We can read the documentation. Which says for `rgValue`, *Pointer to an array of CRYPT_INTEGER_BLOB structures.* In fact, we could just read the field names and see `cValue` and `rgValue` and infer that `cValue` was the count.

Comment: 1 element this is also array. always `T* pt` is pointer to array we can say and reference in as `*pt` or `pt[0]`. simply array can have single element or variable. if we have only  `T* pt` this is mean pointer to single element (array). we have `T* pt; ULONG nt` - pointer to `nt` elements array

Comment: @RbMm, I don't like this phrasing that conflates a scalar and a unit-length array. These are not the same types in C. `T*` is not a pointer to an array. It's a pointer to a scalar `T` value, i.e. when dereferenced, the result is a scalar value, not an array. `T*` may point to the first element of a `T[]` array.

Comment: @eryksun - in *c* very weak difference between pointer to object `T* a` and array of objects `T a[n]`. actually  array is also pointer. may be const pointer if we declare as `T a[n]`. but if pass this as function arument - we can do this as `void fn (T a[])` where `a` already not const pointer to array. (can do `a++` say). or can declare function as `void fn(T* a)` - binary code will be the same as in first case. which src code form select most question of style. at least it seems to me so. I'm not at all *c/c++* programmer

Comment: *`T*` is not a pointer to an array* - i mean by sense, by binary data - we can consider single element as 1 element array. not by formal language definitons

Comment: @RbMm, an array is not a pointer; they are completely different at the binary level. A pointer variable is a symbol for a memory location that contains a machine-sized address, whereas an array is a symbol for a memory location of the first element of an array of values of the given type. Also, semantically, dereferencing a `T*` is a scalar `T`. You cannot pass or return the dereferenced value as a pointer, whereas a C array such as `T a[1]` degenerates as a pointer to the first element in this case.

Comment: @eryksun here `void fn(T a[])` - `a` pointer or array ? this i mean. here `a` is pointer size variable. but look like (by syntax `[]`) as array. in other case, when we declare `T a[n]` (in structure, stack, global data) - `a` of course already not hold any memory itself, but constant offset from register(this), stack, image base.. but initial question was `T* a` - a is pointer to single `T` data or to array of n `T`. by fact first is case of second (array of 1 T). actual  count in `cAttr` - which can be and 0, and 1 and any

Comment: @RbMn, in `void fn(T a[])`, the parameter `a` is a pointer, and, at the binary level, the indexing operation is fundamentally different from indexing an array, but both yield a `T` value.  This is a convenience syntax for `T *a`, as a *hint* to the reader that `fn` is normally called with a pointer to an array, since C doesn't support passing or returning actual array aggregates. A `T *a` is a pointer to a `T`; that is all we know. It may point to a `T` that's the first element of an array, or the 42nd, or to a scalar `T` value. We cannot know the answer sans context in code and documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PCRYPT_ATTR_BLOB` is `CRYPT_ATTR_BLOB*`, pointer to `CRYPT_ATTR_BLOB`. This can either be a pointer to a single value, or a pointer to an array. You can't tell from the type declaration and must read the documentation.

That [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381139.aspx) says:

> **cValue**
>
> A **DWORD** value that indicates the number of elements in the **rgValue**
>   array.
>
> **rgValue**
>
> Pointer to an array of **CRYPT_INTEGER_BLOB** structures.

So in this case `rgValue` is a pointer to an array.

Comment: thanks, I've got not only the answer but a further direction

Comment: The `rg` prefix always marks an array, so that you *can* tell by looking at the declaration.

Answer (score 2):

`rgAttr` and `rgValue` are of type pointer to `struct` :

```
typedef struct _CRYPT_ATTRIBUTES *PCRYPT_ATTRIBUTES;
typedef struct _CRYPT_ATTRIBUTE *PCRYPT_ATTRIBUTE;
```

Now when you do `PCRYPT_ATTRIBUTE rgAttr`, it will be quivalent to `struct _CRYPT_ATTRIBUTE *rgAttr` and to `CRYPT_ATTRIBUTE *rgAttr`.

Generally speaking, using `typedef` on `pointers` has only drawbacks. The only case that `typedef` on `pointer` is actually helpful is when the pointer is a function pointer.

Comment: it's not even an array((  they only use the [] notation

Comment: In your case those pointers are assigned to point to some arrays(you treat them as arrays and not pointers), that's why they use the array notation.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: it explains why they use the array notation when accessing those struct members. I don't understand why it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question in my view. The question is "how do you know whether it's an array or a single value"? The answer is that you read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that MS is pretty constant in the Hungarian-style name decoration, the "rg" prefix tells you it's an array even without going to the docs.